# Using bukhantsov.org command line query output with options

Tags: batch-file, cmd, business-objects, crystal-reports-server

I am trying to use the tool here [business objects query builder output](http://bukhantsov.org/2012/09/command-line-infostore-query-builder-with-export-to-excel/)

And there are virtually no examples, so I'm struggling to make it work.  It produces no errors, but outputs no file in the directory where the batch file is, that I can see.

Here is the code inside querybuilder.bat:

```
set lib=c:\Program Files\Business Objects\Common\4.0\java\lib

java -cp "querybuilder.jar;poi-3.8-20120326.jar;%lib%\*" org.bukhantsov.querybuilder.Program %*
```

Here is the code inside what I am running, which I've named RunQuery_ALLACTIVE.bat, except of course with my Server, Username, and Password changed for the purpose of this post.

I have this all on one line, with no line breaks.

```
querybuilder.bat -cms:SERVER -username:OURUSERNAME -password:OURPASSWORD -query:"SELECT * FROM CI_INFOOBJECTS where SI_SCHEDULE_STATUS = 9 order by SI_NAME" -auth:windowsad -excel "Output.xls"
```

1. Can't tell if the - options go on different LINES ?
2. Can't tell if I'm supposed to put output file in quotes, or if it should be an existing file or not?
3. can't tell if for Windows AD (which we use), I would put "Windows AD" or WindowsAD, I'm assuming no spaces obviously.

Tons of unanswered questions on this tool - it LOOKS cool, but has anyone actually successfully used it?  Can't really find comments or history on the 'net..

Comment: I haven't used this myself (hence posting this as a comment), but I think you may just be missing a : after -excel, i.e. `-excel:"Output.xls"`.  Regarding putting the options on different lines, that's simply not possible with command-line programs.

Comment: OK, thanks Joe.  I did miss the colon.  Thank you for weighing in.

Comment: Did the missing colon answer your question? If so consider [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: No, unfortunately nothing worked, still.  Random freeware things on the web with almost zero documenation and zero knowledge base...can be oh so frustrating, but I guess the takeaway is at the end of the day they probably weren't a good dependency to introduce to my business's daily process anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. The options go on the same line, not on different ones
2. As Joe said, you'll need to specify the output file as `-excel:"Output.xls"`
3. If you want to use Windows AD, you'll probably need to specify `secWinAD` (case-sensitive).

If you're not sure about the command line options, I suggest you build up gradually: first only specify the required options, then add the optional ones one by one so you know which one is giving you problems.

Also, I noticed that the download page contains a version compiled for XI3.x and BI4. Make sure you use the correct version, corresponding to the version of BusinessObjects you're using. Also, verify the path in the batch file to see if it points to a valid folder containing the JAR files for the BusinessObjects environment.

**Update:**

I just noticed that the same author/developer created another application (GUI, not command line) that might be a bit easier to use. Have a look [here](http://bukhantsov.org/2012/03/query-builder-with-export-to-excel/).